# Adding gesture recognizer to UIImageView in a tableView with swift

Tags: xcode, swift, user-interface

I am making an instagram like app but i want the images to be able to swipe left or right for likes. I am using xcode with swift and also parse.this is what i have so far but for some reason im getting no reaction from the code it isnt working for me. How can i make the gesture recognizer work for me so that the image itself can be swiped left or right to receive or lose a point?

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class HomePage: UITableViewController {
var xFromCenter: CGFloat = 0
var images = [UIImage]()
var titles = [String]()
var imageFile = [PFFile]()



   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println(PFUser.currentUser())

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")

    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

            for object in objects! {

                self.titles.append(object["Title"] as! String)

                self.imageFile.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println(error)
        }
    }
    var imageFile: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    imageFile.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.view.addSubview(imageFile)



    var gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged:"))
    imageFile.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

    imageFile.userInteractionEnabled = true


}



func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {



        let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
        var label = gesture.view!

        xFromCenter += translation.x

        var scale = min(100 / abs(xFromCenter), 1)

        label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x + translation.x, y: label.center.y + translation.y)

        gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

        var rotation:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(xFromCenter / 200)

        var stretch:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(rotation, scale, scale)

        label.transform = stretch



        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            if label.center.x < 100 {

                println("Not Chosen")



            } else if label.center.x > self.view.bounds.width - 100 {

                println("Chosen")


                             }

}
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return titles.count


}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 500

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! cell



    myCell.rank.text = "21"
    myCell.votes.text = "4012"
    myCell.postDescription.text = titles[indexPath.row]


    imageFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            myCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage
            myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true


        }

    }

    return myCell

}

}
```

how can i make the swiping work?

Comment: `wasDragged` method is not being called?

Comment: Why don't you use **UISwipeGestureRecognizer**?

Comment: isnt the wasDragged method being called in: var gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged:"))
    imageFile.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

    imageFile.userInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: @kelin can i use UISwipeGestureRecognizer for only the specific image in the cell of the tableview?

Comment: @DanielWolfgangTrebek, yes.

Comment: @kelin would i put that in the tableview or should i put that in the cell?

Comment: @DanielWolfgangTrebek, you can do it both ways. You can put unique recognizer in each cell, or you can put single recognizer to the tableView and use `locationInView` to determine the target cell.